# VBA Backing up Excel file on SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to create back up of the file on SharePoint. When I use ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "https://sharepoint.com/personal/Documents/Test2.xlsm" it works fine the file be saved into the target folder on SharePoint. But when I change the command to ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Error message will appear

[image: Error message]

Comment: Are you using SaveCopyAs to save the file with the same extension?

Comment: Yes I am. Just now I have noticed I have used the different extension in printscreen but I have tried it just now with the same extension (just to be sure) and the result is the same...